# Can you create an array with mathematical equations in VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, math

I have been trying for a while now to create a jagged array filled with mathematical equations, like a*b or (a-b)/c. Equations like that. I have created a windows forms and worked on it for quite a while, and I've come to the point where I want to make the code more compact. I've tweaked here and there, but I seem to struggle heavily with making an array with these equations. What I have so far:

```
Dim mathEqu()() As Object = {
{values(1) / values(15), values(2) - values(1), values(3) - values(4)},
{values(0) * values(15), values(2) - values(0), values(14) / values(7)},
```

etc.

Naturally this array doesn't work, and since I'm basically a rookie, I can't see how I can fix it.

'values()' is an array, by the way, containing 16 different values gotten from textboxes and the missing values are calculated and written in the textboxes containing a '0' (untouched by the user).

Is there a way to create an array solely inhabited by the equations?

Please do ask, if there's anything you need to know in order to help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please be more precise as to what you mean by "mathematical equations." Do you mean an expression evaluated with particular values so the result is a number, which is what you seem to mean in your example? Would strings suffice, with each string storing the expression (such as "a*b")? Or do you need something more mathematical, where you do not yet know the values to use but they could easily be substituted into the expression to get a result?

Comment: How about using a List(Of List(Of Integer))? Or whatever the data type of these numbers are.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Hello, thanks for the welcome! Sorry, yes. It is like an expression, where an Array (values) stores values which is then used in these equations. That is why, so far, I'm using values(n) in the expression. I suppose you could use expressions such as "a*b" to refer to, instead of having it say "values(2) * values(8)" (referring to the value-array). With a little work-around it might work, although if there were any other ways of having expressions stored, as in my example, I would prefer that method.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b they are stored as Double, but yes. You might've just given me an idea. Not necessarily a list, but it definitely should work, considering the "values(9) + values(13)" refers to 2 Double-numbers being added together.

Comment: You aren't storing mathematical equation but the result of equation, just simple normal double values.

Comment: @the_lotus That is exactly what I realized, haha. This might be doable after all that I've been through. Now for the "final" stretch to learn a little about jagged arrays and I should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a huge work-around, creating a Boolean Array for flags for the values() and 2 other Boolean Arrays, one to set a flag whenever one of the equations in mathEqu() was solvable (when all values in an equation/expression was NOT 0) and the other to help set up a flag (like I said, huge work-around).

Here's roughly how the math works in my code:

```
Public Class NPNpositive

    Dim values(15) As Double
    Dim i = 0
    Dim j As Double = 0
    Dim k = 0
    Dim l = 0
    Dim p = 0

// Whenever you click the calculation-button

    Private Sub Calculation_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculation.Click

        Dim tbArray() As TextBox = New TextBox() {IB, IC, IE, .. .., URC, hfe}
        Dim tbBool() As Boolean = New Boolean() {False, False, False, .. .., False, False}
        For Each number In values
            If i < 16 Then
                If Double.TryParse(tbArray(i).Text, j) Then
                    values(i) = j
                End If
            End If
            i += 1
            j = 0
        Next

        Dim mathBool As Boolean()() = {
            New Boolean() {False, False, False},
            New Boolean() {False, False, False},
            New Boolean() {False, False},
            ..,
            ..,
            New Boolean() {False, False}
            New Boolean() {False}}

Calculations:

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        p = 0


// Raising a True-flag if the value in values(i) does not equal 0

        For Each n In values
            If Not values(i) = 0 Then
                tbBool(i) = True
            End If
            i += 1
        Next


// Raising a True-flag when an expression is do-able

        Dim mathBoolHelp As Boolean() = {
            tbBool(1) And tbBool(15),
            tbBool(2) And tbBool(1),
            tbBool(3) And tbBool(4),
            tbBool(0) And tbBool(15),
            tbBool(2) And tbBool(0),
            tbBool(14) And tbBool(7),
            tbBool(12) And tbBool(8),
            ..,
            ..,
            tbBool(11) And tbBool(10),
            tbBool(1) And tbBool(7),
            tbBool(1) And tbBool(0)}

// Here is where the calculations are happening

        Dim mathEqu As Double()() = {
            New Double() {values(1) / values(15), values(2) - values(1), values(3) - values(4)},
            New Double() {values(0) * vlaues(15), values(2) - values(0), values(14) / values(7)},
            New Double() {values(12) / values(8), values(0) + values(1)},
            ..,
            ..,
            New Double() {values(11) - values(10), values(1) * values(7)},
            New Double() {values(1) / values(0)}}

i = 0

// This is where things start to look interesting
// The mathBoolHelp puts in flags in the Boolean jagged Array

        For Each m in values
            j = mathBool(i).Length
            For value As Integer = 0 To j - 1
                If mathBoolHelp(p) = True Then
                    mathBool(i)(k) = True
                End If
                k += 1
                p += 1
            Next
            i += 1
            k = 0
        Next

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

// It checks now in the counter-Boolean Array for a True
// If it finds a true at dimension k, column i, in mathBool()(), it calculates
// the number from the same spot, just from mathEqu()() instead

        For Each m In values
            If values(i) = 0 Then
                j = mathEqu(i).Length
                For value As Integer = 0 To j - 1
                    If mathBool(i)(k) = True Then
                        values(i) = mathEqu(i)(k)
                    End If
                    If Not values(i) = 0 Then
                        GoTo forEnd
                    End If
                    k += 1
                Next
forEnd:
            End If
            i += 1
            k = 0
        Next
```

This is a small portion of the whole program. The main problem was to calculate ONLY when both/all of the values, which was needed to calculate in that very position in the array, was NOT 0. My previous code worked just that way, but it had 16 long If-statements with various lengths. And it was not pretty to look at.

There might be a better solution to my problem, so until then, this will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a roundabout way..

Add a reference to your program. In the references window click on the "Com" tab and search for ""Microsoft Script Control 1.0" . Tick the box to the left of it and click ok at the bottom of the window.

Then you merely need to define a simple string array of formulas - like so ..

```
Dim formula() As String = {"(a+b)/c", "(a^2+b^2)", "a^b"}
```

Add the following function which will take the string expression, and the parameters of the expression. It then replaces the letters in the formula with the parameters you supply and evaluate the resulting expression. Job Done

```
Private Function EvaluateExpression(exp As String, Optional a As Double = 0, Optional b As Double = 0, Optional c As Double = 0) As Double
    Dim SC As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    exp = exp.Replace("a", a.ToString)
    exp = exp.Replace("b", b.ToString)
    exp = exp.Replace("c", c.ToString)
    SC.Language = "VBSCRIPT"
    Dim Result As Double = Convert.ToDouble(SC.Eval(exp))
    Return Result
End Function
```